# Convert rows to columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one case of displaying the result from mysql. I need convert rows to columns in mysql.

This is my example :

```
generator   |turbine  |trafo   |hour
========================================
1           |20       |13      |09:00:00
3           |21       |15      |10:00:00
4           |25       |17      |11:00:00
9           |29       |11      |12:00:00
```

The result I need :

```
hour        |09:00:00   |10:00:000   |11:00:00   |12:00:00
==========================================================
trafo       |13         |15          |17         |11
turbine     |20         |21          |25         |29
generator   |1          |3           |4          |9
```

or (if possible) :

```
09:00:00   |10:00:000   |11:00:00   |12:00:00
=============================================
13         |15          |17         |11
20         |21          |25         |29
1          |3           |4          |9
```

Can I show these results through mysql query?

Info : hours use time type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but a pain:

```
select t,
       sum(case when hour = '09:00:00' then val else 0 end) as hour_09,
       sum(case when hour = '10:00:00' then val else 0 end) as hour_10,
       sum(case when hour = '11:00:00' then val else 0 end) as hour_11
from (select 'generator' as which, generator as val, hour from t union all
      select 'turbine', turbine, hour from t union all
      select 'trafo', trafo, hour from t
     ) t
group by t
```